Need Help Integrating Vuetify Vue.js Template into Electron
I'm attempting to integrate a Vue.js application built with Vuetify into an Electron desktop application. The Vue.js application was created using the Vite build tool. However, despite following various tutorials and guides, I've been unable to successfully integrate it into Electron. I suspect there may be configuration issues or missing steps in the process.
I've used the following Vue.js Vuetify template file with Vite: Google Drive
I've tried following tutorials and guides available online for integrating Vue.js applications into Electron. Specifically, I've attempted to modify the Electron main script (main.js), adjusted paths for static assets in the Vue.js code, and ensured that the Vue.js application builds correctly using Vite. Additionally, I've experimented with different Electron builder tools such as electron-builder. However, despite these efforts, I haven't been able to achieve a working integration.
I expected that by following the provided tutorials and guides, I would be able to successfully bundle my Vue.js application into an Electron desktop application, allowing it to run as a standalone application on users' machines. However, the Electron application fails to load the Vue.js components properly, indicating that there may be an issue with the integration process that I'm unable to identify.
I'm seeking assistance in understanding where I might be going wrong in the integration process and how to resolve any configuration issues or missing steps. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

The question is too unspecific for SO. I'd suggest to approach it from the other side and get a usable Electron+Vite setup, then you can start adding Vue and Vuetify to it. It's unknown what's your template because the access is restricted, maybe you can just copy most of src/ or maybe start from scratch if there's nothing much useful

I appreciate your suggestion to approach it with the Electron+Vite side.
I'm currently using Electron Forge for my project. After building the Vue.js project and starting the server from the root folder, I encounter the error "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of 'text/plain'."
This error occurs in an index.html file in the dist folder. Interestingly, serving the project directly from the dist directory in the Vue.js project works fine. Any insights or suggestions on fixing this within the Electron Forge setup would be appreciated.

You may check first @electron-forge/plugin-vite then. Needs to be checked what's going on and why a script is loaded from wrong url, this is the likely reason for text/plain.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hope this helps clarify, this is my project structure
electron-app/
│
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.js
│   └── ...
├── vue-app/
│   └── dist/
│   └── index.html
│   ├── assets/
when i npm start the project from the electron dir electron-app, i get error
"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec." which shows it's from the dist dir index.html
